# Passing Data on Navigation

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I need to pass data to the home page when the user is logged in. I need to pass the username to the home page.

```
public void Login(string Username, string password)
{
    // ..... Do login and if success
    var Logindata = database.GetUsername(_usernamelogin);

    Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Homepage(Logindata));

}
```

My method to get the user name is

```
public Register_person GetUsername(string mail1)
{
    return Conn.Table<Register_person>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.UserName == mail1);
}
```

my home page XAML

In my home page code behind cs, I retrieve the incoming data

```
public Register_person register_Person;
public Homepage (Register_person loindata)
{
    InitializeComponent ();
    l1.Text = logindata.UserName;
}
```

This code works, I can get the username. But I am using MVVM and not sure how to implement this in MVVM.

Comment: Microsoft has some sample apps. Start reading the source [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps/blob/master/src/BikeSharing.Clients.Core/Services/NavigationService.cs)

Comment: You want to know how to change your current project to `MVVM` structure? To pass data, you can also pass the value as a parameter to the constructor of `homePage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pure MVVM way of doing this would be to abstract the navigation and invoke it from your viewmodel (see [Prisms navigation service](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/navigation-basics.html) as a reference). Anyway, there can be quite some pitfalls in implementing such a navigation service. If at any rate possible I'd suggest to integrate Prism in your solution and go full MVVM.

There is, however, a hybrid approach that would be way easier to implement, but is not pure MVVM. Assuming that you are not injecting dependencies you could define your binding directly in your XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             xmlns:generic="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=netstandard"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage"
             x:Name="Page">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <!-- Your content goes here -->

</ContentPage>
```

Within your viewmodel you can now define a command to log the user in and an event that is used to communicate to your view that the user was logged in successfully (please note that this code is stripped down to the *bare minimum*)

```
class ViewModel
{
    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:System.Object"></see> class.</summary>
    public ViewModel()
    {
        LogInCommand = new Command(OnLogIn);
    }

    private void OnLogIn()
    {
        // your login logic shall go here
        // your password and user name shall be bound 
        // via other properties

        // Invoke the LoggedIn event with the user name 
        // of the logged in user.
        LoggedIn?.Invoke(userName);
    }

    public event Action<string> LoggedIn;

    public Command LogInCommand { get; }
}
```

From your view you can subscribe to `LoggedIn`

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:ViewModel LoggedIn="ViewModel_OnLoggedIn" />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

And of course you need the respective method in your code behind (the `.xaml.cs` file)

```
private void ViewModel_OnLoggedIn(string obj)
{
    // navigate the other page here
}
```

This is not a solution you can plug in directly, but should point you to the right direction. **Please note** that you'll have to bind some `Button` or something else to `LogInCommand`, as well as entries to properties for the username and password.